# Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]> , any one can help me

Tags: json, angular

i got this error: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>: when i set in angular service.ts when i wanna to impelement http

Comment: Could you post some example code for what's happening here? By the sounds of it, it looks like you have a variable with type Observable<User[]> and you're trying to assign a value that's just type Observable (less specific). You could always try to force things your way if you know the value is really Observable<User[]> with something like 

this.myvariable = someValue as Observable<User[]>;

Comment: Please show us the code. If this is part of a server call, it could be a return type issue. Can't say more without seeing a minimal representation of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're trying to fetch the data using `HttpClient` service, but you changed the default response type to be `arraybuffer` instead of `JSON`:

```js
// This should work, because it returns the result as `Observable<User[]>`
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>('YOUR_API_URL');
}

// This won't work, because it returns the result as as `Observable<ArrayBuffer>`
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get('YOUR_API_URL', {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer', // <<< This option will read the result as `arrayBuffer` instead of JSON.
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the workaround?